# Why my server do have TEE but don't support Intel SGX?

Tags: intel, tee, sgx

My server cpu is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214 CPU @ 2.20GHz [The detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qssw5.png)

I wonder why this CPU support TEE but don't support Intel SGX? whta's the point? is there any way I can install SGX by myself or run SGX program on this server?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU supports TXT (Trusted Execution Technology), not TEE (Trusted execution environment).

TXT is a different technology. You can read it up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Execution_Technology).